irreducible factors in group determinant
I want to prove the irreducible part of Frobenius’ theorem, that is to say,

If $\rho$ is a irreducible representation, then $P(x_1,x_2,\cdots, x_n)=\text{det}(\sum_{s_i \in G} x_i\rho(s_i))$ is irreducible on $\mathbb{C}\left[ x_1, x_2, \cdots,x_n \right]$.

If $P=P_1\cdot P_2,$ I guess that we have $\rho=\rho_1\oplus\rho_2,$ such that $P_k=\text{det}(\sum_{s_i \in G} x_i\rho_k(s_i)), $ where $\text{deg} \;P_k\geq1.$ I do not know whether this conjecture is right or not, and I have no idea on other approaches.
Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Your guess isn't right due to a small normalization problem: you did not rescale the factors $P_1$ and $P_2$ so the leading coefficient of $x_e^{\deg \rho_1}$ and $x_e^{\deg \rho_2}$ are $1$, which is necessary in order that they have the form you want.
When that normalization is made, your idea still isn't the best way to approach the irreducibility. Let $d =\dim \rho$. It turns out that the $d^2$ linear polynomials that are the matrix entries in $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\rho(s_i)$ turn out to be algebraically independent over $\mathbf C$ and it is a standard property that when $\{t_{ij}\}$ is a set of $d^2$ algebraically independent elements over a field $K$, the polynomial $\det (t_{ij})$ in $K[t_{11},\ldots,t_{dd}]$ is irreducible.
Details behind this approach are in Section $5$ here, especially Theorem $4$(i).
